# Can I Use Task.CompletedTask to Detect if Virtual Method was Overridden?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have an asp.net core web application with an abstract class with a virtual method that child classes may or may not override. I want to execute different logic based on whether it was overridden or not and was wondering if the below check is a good idea or not:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        var task = OverrideMe();
        bool wasOverridden = task != Task.CompletedTask;
        await task;

        if (wasOverridden)
        {
            //Virtual method was overridden
        }
        else
        {
            //Virtual method was not overridden
        }
    }

    protected virtual Task OverrideMe()
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I realize that if the child class returns `Task.CompletedTask` it would still look like it wasn't overridden. But if we ignore that fact, would this check work? What I'm most concerned about is the `Id` field of the task. Would that change and maybe cause the equality comparison to fail? When I test my code above it works but what if there are other async tasks running in parallel etc?

Comment: While in practice, the above might work, I'd not recommend doing it. You have no guarantee that `Task.CompletedTask` returns a constant. It could return a new instance each time you call it. I sense you have an X-Y problem there. What would you do if the task is not overridden? If it is just for throwing an error, I would just make the `OverrideMe` method really abstract. Then it's a compile-time error not to override it.

Comment: I'm curious in what way your two commented code blocks would differ.  What do you do differently in the two cases?  In my opinion, having to check whether a subclass overrode your method from in the base class is an indication of a flawed design somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I recommend re-addressing the design. If possible, a base class should not change behavior when a derived class overrides a method. Perhaps the base type should define a property of an interface type that the derived type could choose set or leave `null`. Bottom line is that "detecting whether an override exists" is a huge red flag from a design perspective.

That said, I have done it once in my (almost) 25 years of programming. My ConnectedProperties library has a validation check to attempt to ensure correct usage; connected properties only work for types treated as reference types, so it checks [if the type overrides `Equals`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/ConnectedProperties/blob/e7ff62c814582a2ddab18236193cfae8a6b69da0/src/Nito.ConnectedProperties/ConnectedPropertyScope.cs#L147) as a heuristic for "type treated as a value type".

If you *must* use this questionable design, then reflection is the only real way to go; find the methods on that type hierarchy matching the name and parameters of `OverrideMe` and then check to see whether their base definitions are the `OverrideMe` from the base type.

Answer (score 3):

What if you set a private field when the method has no overwrite like this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    private bool _notOverwritten;
    public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        var task = OverrideMe();
        
        await task;

        if (!_notOverwritten)
        {
            //Virtual method was overridden
        }
        else
        {
            //Virtual method was not overridden
        }
    }

    protected virtual Task OverrideMe()
    {
        _notOVerwritten = true;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

EDIT: This solution does not work completely as a derived class can still call `base.OverrideMe()` like @Theodor Zoulias mentioned.

You could throw an exception when the `base.OverrideMe()` is called and catch it in the `DoSomethingAsync` but again the derived class can also catch this exception.

Comment: But a derived class can still call `base.OverrideMe()` in the implementation of the overridden `OverrideMe` method.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yeah, edited my answer to say it is not completely correct.